# Simba SFDC ODBC Driver Error Message (-7711)

Tags: odbc, salesforce, simba

I'm using Simba's Salesforce ODBC Driver and keep getting error message (-7711). Below is the what I believe to be part of the log where the error resides but I'm unable to determine what's causing the error message and how to resolve it. Can anyone offer advise?

```
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 SFConnection::SFConnection: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 Connection::SQLGetInfoW: InfoType: SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER (77)
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 Connection::SQLGetInfoW: InfoType: SQL_ASYNC_DBC_FUNCTIONS (10023)
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 Connection::SQLGetInfoW: InfoType: SQL_ASYNC_NOTIFICATION (10025)
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: Attribute: SQL_ATTR_ANSI_APP (115)
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionState::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionAttributes::SetAttribute: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: Attribute: SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT (103)
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionState::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionAttributes::SetAttribute: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 Connection::SQLGetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 Connection::SQLGetConnectAttr: Attribute: Unknown Attribute (30002)
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionState2::SQLGetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 ERROR 1276 Connection::SQLGetConnectAttr: [Simba][ODBC] (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported: 30002
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: Attribute: Unknown Attribute (30002)
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionState::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionAttributes::SetAttribute: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 ConnectionAttributes::SetAttribute: Invalid attribute: 30002
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 ERROR 1276 Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: [Simba][ODBC] (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported: 30002
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 Connection::SQLDriverConnectW: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 TRACE 1276 ConnectionState2::SQLDriverConnectW: +++++ enter +++++
Mar 07 16:48:57.062 INFO  1276 ConnectionSettings::LoadSettings: ConnString setting: "DSN" = "Simba Salesforce"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Roman no, we've moved on and begun exploring other solutions